# Restricting a model to only view their own items in the has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, devise

So I'm trying to think about how to route my site and I need a little help.  I have a business who can .build (as in business creates) buildings (sorry for the repetition haha) in a has_many.  Each property has many something else.

I would like it so even though there will be more than one building, each business should only be able to view their own buildings, so if someone tries to alter a url, it would redirect home.

I have

```
resources :buildings
```

so as it is set up, anyone could just type in

host/buildings/whatever

I would like to redirect with an error if the building ID does not belong to the current_business (devise) it will redirect to their home page.  each building has a business_id

Would I have to break the RESTful for this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have `user_id` in `builduing` resource:

**buildings_controller.rb**

```
def index
 @buildings = current_user.buildings
end

def show
 @building = current_user.buildings.find(params[:id])
end
```

**buildings/index.html.erb**

```
<% @buildings.each do |building| %>
  <%= building.whatever_atribute %>
<% end %>
```

**buildings/show.html.erb**

```
<%= @building.whatever_atribute %>
```

With the above code when user will go to `/buildings` he will see only his buildings, and if he'll go to `buildings/3` he will see this building if he owns it, in other case he will see a `not found` error that you can customize it with a redirect or display a styled page.

Comment: Ah perfect. This makes perfect sense I can't believe I didn't get here on my own...